# Erlang erlydtl rendering mnesia records

Tags: erlang

I have the following record definition:

`-record(contact, {name, email})`

Assuming that I have a few contacts in the mnesia database already and I want to render them with erlydtl on an html page, I first query the database:

`F = fun() -> qlc:e(qlc:q([X || X <- mnesia:table(contact)])) end,

{atomic, Contacts} = mnesia:transaction(F).`

Having my contacts stored in the Contacts variable, and having a contacts.html file, I try to render it so (the below code is happening inside a misultin callback):

`erlydtl:compile("contacts.html", contacts),

contacts:render(Contacts).`

The contacts.html file is as following:

`{% for contact in contacts %}

{{ contact.name }}

{{ contact.email }}

{% endfor %}`

The above obviously does not work.
Help!

Thank you.

-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mochiweb_util](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochiweb_util.erl) provides `record_to_proplist/2` and `record_to_proplist/3` which work nicely. These are also dynamic with regards to the records you pass in.

Answer (score 3):

I hope a nicer solution exists, but you could define an helper function like:

```
contact_to_list(C) ->
    lists:zip(record_info(fields, contact), tl(tuple_to_list(C))).
```

And pass that to ErlyDTL:

```
your_template:render([{contact, contact_to_list(C)}]).
```

*UPDATE*: If you want to make this 'dynamic', so that you can pass a variable instead of an atom to the record_info, you can use the 'exprecs' parse transform:

http://doc.erlagner.org/parse_trans/exprecs.html

Basically, after you add the parse_trans app as a dependency, you can add the following to your module:

```
-compile({parse_transform, exprecs}).
-export_records([
    contact
]).
```

And then have your new dynamic function:

```
record_to_list(Rec, RecName) ->
        lists:zip('#info-'(RecName), tl(tuple_to_list(Rec))).
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to pass record_info a variable instead of an atom of the record as I would like to have a dynamic query and will not know in advance the name of the record?

Comment: I've added some details about exprecs to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Roberto. Is there a way to replace the contact atom in the export_records directive with a Variable otherwise it would not be completely dynamic. I am reading the name of tables from a file and then I create CRUD functions for mnesia therefore I do not know the name of the records but it depends on the person creating the tables.